# Adding events to button doesn't work with backbone

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, jquery-events

I read over 20 different articles and forum topics about that, tried different solutions but I didn't cope with it. 
The following code doesn't work. I need someone's help...

LoginView.js

```
var LoginView = Backbone.View.extend({   
    //el: $('#page-login'),
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'gotoLogin', 'render');
        //this.render();
    },

    events: {
        'click #button-login': 'gotoLogin'
    },

    gotoLogin : function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $('#signup-or-login').hide();           
        $('#login').show();
        return true;
    }       
});
```

login.html

```
<div data-role="page" id="page-login">

<!-- SignUp or Login section-->
<div id="signup-or-login" data-theme="a">
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="button-signup"> Sign Up </a>
    <a data-role="button" data-theme="x" id="button-login"> Login </a>      
</div>

<!-- Login section--> 
<div id="login" data-theme="a">
    <button data-theme="b"> Login </button>
    <button data-theme="x"> Cancel </button>
</div>

</div>
```

The page is created in method of Backbone.Router extended class.

```
loadPage('login.html', new LoginView());
```

Comment: what does your render function look like?

Comment: When do you set the `el` for the `LoginView`?

Comment: Is your `el` property commented out for a reason? Try passing the id without making a jQuery object out of it. Backbone automatically creates `$el` on render.

Comment: @Vic I use render function of the base View class I suppose. I tried to write render function here as well but it didn't help

Comment: @KevinPeel I have defined el element inside Router loadPage function: 
     `var loadPage = function (url, view) {
            $.mobile.loadPage(url, true).done(function (absUrl, options, page) {
                var pageId = page.attr('id');
                view.$el = page;
                view.render();
                $.mobile.changePage('#' + pageId);
            });
        };`

Comment: You need to have a render function, what do you mean the render function from the base view class? The default render function doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Vic What should I code in render function if I have everything in html file? There are no dynamic data for this page. Maybe I have bad understanding what render function does...

Comment: `_.bindAll(this, 'gotoLogin', 'render');` this will cause errors if there is no `render()` defined

Comment: @benhowdle89 fixed. But it doesn't work either with render function or without it. My render function is `render: function(){ return this; }`

Comment: @WillM I've uncommented and put `el: '#page-login'`. It doesn't help :(

Comment: What do you get when you: `var v = new LoginView();` `console.log(v.el, v.$el);`? I want to make sure it's setting the element correctly.

Comment: @WillM `undefined [context: document, selector: "#page-login", jquery: "1.10.1", constructor: function, init: function…]`

Comment: @WillM if I comment `//el: '#page-login'` I get `<div></div> [div, jquery: "1.10.1", constructor: function, init: function, selector: "", toArray: function…]
`

Comment: Maybe it renders login.html again. I don't need it, I just need to hide one html part and show another one... Upd: No, I don't see any get/post request after button click

Comment: Okay, it's not finding `#page-login`. Is the html loaded before you instantiate your view? Side note: Backbone automatically creates a `div` element if you don't specify one to attached to.

Comment: Alright, first of all, is there a reason you're not putting the html into a template and using the view's render to attach it to the DOM? This is how backbone view is meant to be used.

Comment: @WillM Could you see the screenshot? [link](https://pp.vk.me/c419526/v419526495/8e88/E6fSE8X04H8.jpg) el is right div while login.html is loading

Comment: @WillM Sorry incorrect link, now is correct

Comment: Thanks, @Tetyana. That is helpful. `View.$el` is managed by the `Backbone` view. Looking through the annotated source of [`setElement()`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-126), it looks like you should assign it to `View.el` instead.

Comment: @WillM I've just tried it, but it doesn't help :( `loadPage('login.html', new LoginView());` View variable is an object of LoginView... Maybe changePage function causes some crash to View.el...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, `$.mobile.loadPage()` grabs the desired html and attaches it to the DOM.

Currently, you're trying to set `el` after the `View` has been instantiated.

However, notice that Backbone.View attaches `el` and `$el` [when it's instantiated](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-117):

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
  ...
  this._ensureElement();
  this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  this.delegateEvents();
};
```

Also notice that [`View.setElement()`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-126) sets `$el` by passing a selector or a jQuery objected to `View.el`:

```
setElement: function(element, delegate) {
  if (this.$el) this.undelegateEvents();
  this.$el = element instanceof Backbone.$ ? element : Backbone.$(element);
  this.el = this.$el[0];
  if (delegate !== false) this.delegateEvents();
  return this;
}
```

### Bottom line:

You need to set `el` (in your case with the provided jQuery object) while instantiating it:

```
// Where `view` is a reference to the constructor, not an instantiated object
var loadPage = function(url, view) {

  $.mobile.loadPage(url, true).done(function (absUrul, options, page) {
    var v,
        pageId = page.attr('id');

    v = new view({
      el: page
    });

    ...
  }

}
```

You now call `loadPage()` like so:

```
loadPage('login.html', LoginView);
```

This gives `Backbone.View` the `$el` which to delegate your events.